# working with user blocking system in react

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, react-hooks, blocking

I am making a web app like Tinder. Currently, I am working with user blocking. I have a "blocked" table in the database. In my application, A user already can block another user. Now, I want to hide the users in the search result if the logged user already blocked them.

Here is the code I have. This code renders for infinity (it doesn't stop). Can anyone tell me how can I make it working?

```
const ListOfUsers = ({ users }) => {
    //console.log('users list rendered', users)
    var coords = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('loggedMatchaUser'));
    var from_user_id = coords.user_id;
    
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(0)
    const checkBlock = (to_user_id) => {
        blockService.blockedUser({from_user_id, to_user_id})
        .then(res => {
            //If this row exist in the table it return 1 otherwise 0
            setCheck(res.value);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(("Error: couldn't get block info"))
        })
    }
    return (
        users && users.length > 0
            ? <ListGroup className="text-left" variant="flush">
                {users.map(u => <Link to={`/users/${u.user_id}`} key={u.user_id}>
                    {checkBlock(u.user_id)}
                    {!check &&
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <div style={{display: "inline-block", width: "60%"}}>{u.username}, {u.age.years}</div>
                            <div style={{display: "inline-block", width: "40%", textAlign: "right"}}>{parseInt(u.distance)} km<br />
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAward} /> {u.fame}</div>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                    }
                </Link>)}
            </ListGroup>
            : <div className="text-info">Could not find any matching users<br />please try different filters</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Move `checkBlock` method inside `useEffect`

Comment: you mean like this ? 

`useEffect(() => {
  const checkBlock = (to_user_id) => {
   blockService.blockedUser({from_user_id, to_user_id})
   .then(res => {
    //console.log("This is res value"+res.value);
    setCheck(res.value);
   })
   .catch(e => {
    console.log(("Error: couldn't get block info"))
   })
  }
 }, [])
`

Comment: yes the same way..

Answer (score 0):

You are issuing a side-effect (i.e. calling a function that updates state) in the render return.

```
const ListOfUsers = ({ users }) => {
  ...

  const [check, setCheck] = useState(0);

  const checkBlock = (to_user_id) => {
    blockService
      .blockedUser({ from_user_id, to_user_id })
      .then((res) => {
        //If this row exist in the table it return 1 otherwise 0
        setCheck(res.value); // <-- updates state
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Error: couldn't get block info");
      });
  };
  return users && users.length > 0 ? (
    <ListGroup className="text-left" variant="flush">
      {users.map((u) => (
        <Link to={`/users/${u.user_id}`} key={u.user_id}>
          {checkBlock(u.user_id)} // <-- function call updates state
          ...
        </Link>
      ))}
    </ListGroup>
  ) : (
    ...
  );
};
```

You'll likely want to use an effect hook to check blocked users when the `users` prop updates. You'll need to "preprocess" your `users` array and augment it with the blocked status, or simply filter them out, which is probably easier anyway. The reason is because you can't use a single `check` state value for every `user` being rendered.

```
const ListOfUsers = ({ users }) => {
  const coords = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("loggedMatchaUser"));
  const from_user_id = coords.user_id;

  const [nonBlockedUsers, setNonBlockedUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkBlock = (to_user_id) =>
      // If this row exist in the table it return 1 otherwise 0
      blockService.blockedUser({ from_user_id, to_user_id });

    Promise.all(users.map(({ user_id }) => checkBlock(user_id))).then(
      (blockedUserStatus) => {
        const nonBlockedUsers = [];

        users.forEach((user, index) => {
          if (!blockedUserStatus[index]) nonBlockedUsers.push(user);
        });
        setNonBlockedUsers(nonBlockedUsers);
      }
    );
  }, [from_user_id, users]);

  return nonBlockedUsers.length > 0 ? (
    <ListGroup className="text-left" variant="flush">
      {nonBlockedUsers.map((u) => (
        <Link to={`/users/${u.user_id}`} key={u.user_id}>
          <ListGroup.Item>
            <div style={{ display: "inline-block", width: "60%" }}>
              {u.username}, {u.age.years}
            </div>
            <div
              style={{
                display: "inline-block",
                width: "40%",
                textAlign: "right"
              }}
            >
              {parseInt(u.distance)} km
              <br />
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAward} /> {u.fame}
            </div>
          </ListGroup.Item>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </ListGroup>
  ) : (
    <div className="text-info">
      Could not find any matching users
      <br />
      please try different filters
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's could be a nice solution I guess. I was wondering in your solution, how can I get **to_user_id** argument here?
`blockService.blockedUser({ from_user_id, to_user_id });`

Comment: @MahmudulHasan I would say it is passed in `users.map(checkBlock)`, but I just realized your `users` array isn't an array of user ids. I'll update my answer. Basically you need to pass `user.user_id` on in the mapping function: `users.map(({ user_id }) => checkBlock(user_id))`.